# How to find from where the android app deep link is click like it does in open referrer in web?

Tags: android, deep-linking

I need to find what was the source of my app open like(fb,twitter,g+) is there a way to find it.
I know there is a open referrer in header of url but how can i fetch this information in android app

Comment: was this already answered? The answers below didn't work for me.

Answer (score 1):

Google provide online material for this: 
https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/deeplink-referrer

**Summary**

You can use [Activity#getReferrer()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity#getReferrer()) to get the referrer of the deep link. It's available since API 22.

For API Level 21 and below, you can use the following snippet from above online material:

```java
    private static final String REFERRER_NAME = "android.intent.extra.REFERRER_NAME";


 /** Returns the referrer on devices running SDK versions lower than 22. */
    private Uri getReferrerCompatible(Activity activity) {
        Intent intent = activity.getIntent();
        Uri referrerUri = intent.getParcelableExtra(Intent.EXTRA_REFERRER);
        if (referrerUri != null) {
            return referrerUri;
        }
        String referrer = intent.getStringExtra(REFERRER_NAME);
        if (referrer != null) {
            // Try parsing the referrer URL; if it's invalid, return null
            try {
                return Uri.parse(referrer);
            } catch (ParseException e) {
                return null;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Comment: What is the `REFERRER_NAME` stand for ?

Comment: thank you , i added an answer, different approach but works too , yours did not detect some chrome link but i used it as a backup plan

Comment: @Ahmedna Good to have options. In my case, returning "google.com" is expected since user clicking the link inside Google web page, regardless whether he is opening it from Chrome application.

Answer (score 1):

depending on @Ahmad Fadli answer (works but some application might not be detected)
I had a similar use case, so someone might need it , you could use both of them too :

```
fun getReferrerCompatible(activity: Activity?): String? {
    if (activity == null)
        return null
    try {
        val intent = activity.intent
        val bundle = intent.extras
        if (bundle != null) {
            val keySet = bundle.keySet().toTypedArray()
            for (k in keySet) {
                if (k.contains("application_id")) {
                    return bundle.getString(k)
                }

            }
        }
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP_MR1) {
            return activity.referrer?.toString()
        }
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        Crashlytics.logException(e)
    }
    return null
}
```

the default `referrer` actually does not give you chrome application for some deep links ,for some reason it would return "google.com"

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at Firebase Dynamic Links
https://firebase.google.com/docs/dynamic-links/

Comment: I am using 'branch.io', I need to know the source from where the user is coming.

Comment: @AbhishekSingh onInitFinished()  has jsonobject  parameter which contains the source key "~channel"

Answer (score 0):

Try this

On your android manifest file register your acitivity which have to open on link click

```
 <activity
            android:name=".YOURACTIVITY"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
                <data android:scheme="http"
                    android:host="somedomainname.com"
                    android:pathPrefix="/index"/>

            </intent-filter>

        </activity>
```

On your html

```
<a href="android-app:/your android app packagename/http://somedomainname.com/index">Click me</a>
```